# Text align 'center' not working for table header

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, text-align

I have created a table, and am trying to align the text of table header to the center using "align='center'", but it doesn't work even though it works  for table data.

The other problem is that while adding border to table cells using nested for loop, there is this error I get on debugging through chrome:

```
"Cannot read property 'style' of undefined"
```

The same code works on writing the code 10 times without for loop.

Here is the complete function:

```
function makeBookingDetailsTable(rs) 

{  
        var arry = new Array();
        arry = rs.split(", ");
        var table = "<table id='myTable'>";
        var content="";

//ALIGN DOESN'T WORK FOR 'th'
         content += "<tr><th align='center'>" + "Booking Id" + "</th>";
         content += "<th align='center'>" + "CCA Sent" + "</th>";
         content += "<th align='center'>" + "CCA Acknowledged" + "</th>";
         content += "<th align='center'>" + "Folio Received" + "</th></tr>";



 //ALIGN WORKS FOR 'td'        
         for (var i = 0; i < arry.length; i++)
             {

   content += "<tr><td align='center'>" + arry[i] + "</td>";
content += "<td align='center'><select><option value='Yes'>Yes</option><option value='No'>No</option></select></td>";
content +="<td align='center'><select><option value='Yes'>Yes</option><option value='No'>No</option></select></td>"; 
content +="<td align='center'><select><option value='Yes'>Yes</option><option value='No'>No</option></select></td>";    
             }         
         content += "</table>";
         table += content;

        $(document.body).append(table);

        document.getElementById('myTable').style.width="80%";

        document.getElementById('myTable').style.border="2px solid black";

for ( var i=0; i<=arry.length; i++)
{
    for  (var j=0; j<5; j++)
    {
    document.getElementById("myTable").rows[i].cells[j].style.border = "2px solid black" ;

//OUTER LOOP RUNS ONLY ONCE. IF I USE 'rows[0]', 'rows[1]' ETC. IN PLACE OF 'rows[i]' IN ABOVE LINE, THINGS WORK FINE.

     }
}    
}
```

Please help me with these!

Comment: Consider using inline-css (style="text-align: center")

Comment: one of you're rows in table doesn't have  `cell[j]`

Comment: also why not use `<thead>` `<tbody>` and `<tfoot>` to have table header/table body and optional table footer and use td in these no problem

Comment: FedeSc, you're right about that. I can't believe I couldn't find it.

Comment: @Nikos M., that doesn't solve either.

Comment: @Psi, that solved. Thanks a lot.

But why wasn't 'align="center"' working?